# Syntax error MYSQL with PYTHON (simple code)

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I have an errow and I don't know what is it because my query works in MYSQL WORKBENCH but not when I implement it in my python code...

The error is :

```
(1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT i.ID, i.post_title AS 'Title', pm1.meta_value AS 'Prix', pm2.meta_value A' at line 1")
```

So I share the concerned code here :

(i is the mod803_posts table)

```
sql_unique_maisons_appartements =
    ("SET sql_mode = 'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';"
    "SELECT i.ID, i.post_title AS 'Title', pm1.meta_value AS 'Prix', pm2.meta_value AS 'Surface', pm4.meta_value AS 'Ville', "
    "GROUP_CONCAT(t.name) AS 'Category', pm5.meta_value AS 'annee_de_construction', pm6.meta_value AS 'Alarme', pm7.meta_value AS 'aspect', "
    "pm8.meta_value AS 'assainissement', pm9.meta_value AS 'Cave', pm10.meta_value AS 'certificat_assainissement', pm11.meta_value AS 'cuisine' "
    "FROM mod803_posts i "
    "LEFT JOIN mod803_postmeta pm1 ON pm1.post_id = i.ID AND pm1.meta_key = 'Prix de vente' "
    "LEFT JOIN mod803_postmeta pm2 ON pm2.post_id = i.ID AND pm2.meta_key = 'Surface' "
    "LEFT JOIN mod803_postmeta pm4 ON pm4.post_id = i.ID AND pm4.meta_key = 'Ville' "
    "LEFT JOIN mod803_postmeta pm5 ON pm5.post_id = i.ID AND pm5.meta_key = 'annee_de_construction' "
    "LEFT JOIN mod803_postmeta pm6 ON pm6.post_id = i.ID AND pm6.meta_key = 'Alarme' "
    "LEFT JOIN mod803_postmeta pm7 ON pm7.post_id = i.ID AND pm7.meta_key = 'aspect' "
    "LEFT JOIN mod803_postmeta pm8 ON pm8.post_id = i.ID AND pm8.meta_key = 'assainissement' "
    "LEFT JOIN mod803_postmeta pm9 ON pm9.post_id = i.ID AND pm9.meta_key = 'Cave(s)' "
    "LEFT JOIN mod803_postmeta pm10 ON pm10.post_id = i.ID AND pm10.meta_key = 'certificat_assainissement' "
    "LEFT JOIN mod803_postmeta pm11 ON pm11.post_id = i.ID AND pm11.meta_key = 'cuisine' "
    "LEFT JOIN mod803_term_relationships AS tr ON tr.object_id = i.ID "
    "LEFT JOIN mod803_term_taxonomy AS tt ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id AND tt.taxonomy = 'typedestock' "
    "LEFT JOIN mod803_terms AS t ON tt.term_id = t.term_id "
    "WHERE i.post_type in ('stock') "
    "AND i.post_status = 'publish' "
    "AND i.ID = %s "
    "ORDER BY i.ID ASC")
```

(This code works in WORKBENCH...)

If someone can help me... thank you

Comment: Your code does not even run the query!

Comment: What does it means ?

Comment: They're asking you to share more of the code. The way you're executing the query in the Python might be incorrect even if the query string itself is correct.